# Formatting ListView User Selection in Powershell

Tags: listview, powershell

I am trying to output the user's selection from a ListView to a message box for confirmation purposes.

When I write `$ListView.SelectedItems.'Selection'` in a powershell console, the selection comes out in a list format.

```
1
2
3
```

If I try to display the same output in a message box, `[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show(" User has selected: $($ListView.SelectedItems.'Selection')")` 
the output comes out looking like

`User has selected: 1 2 3`

Similarly, using `Write-host $ListView.SelectedItems.'Selection'` in the powershell console outputs all in 1 line also.

How can I format so  I can insert either a comma or period or possibly show it as a list rather than having it all show inline.

Comment: `$($ListView.SelectedItems.Selection -join ", ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you expand an array of data simple types inside a string, like so:

```
"$(@(1,2,3,4))"
```

PowerShell concatenates the values using the ***o***utput **f**ield **s**eparator, stored in the automaric variable `$OFS`. If `$OFS` is `$null`, the separator defaults to a space, as evident from your problem.

Either change the value of `$OFS` before calling `MessageBox.Show()`:

```
$OFS = ', '
$message = "User has selected: $($ListView.SelectedItems.'Selection')"
[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($message)
```

or do the concatenation yourself, with `-join`:

```
$message = "User has selected: $($ListView.SelectedItems.'Selection' -join ', ')"
[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show($message)
```